# Perl script to check file exists in Linux file system

Tags: perl, file, using, exists

I am working on production servers.. I want to check file generated daily and send report via email like file generated or not daily.. I like to use perl script and I might run the script on different server so my script should check on other server where file generates. And also it check for file header and trailer. Please guide me how to check in different system and how to generate as mail content depends upon file exists or not conditions I.e if all file exists content something like all file generated and it contain table with filename and status of the file exists . if file not exists file name should be highlighted and content should be like missing file not generated please investigate... Give me some ideas around this.. Thanks

Summaries:

Just check file exists or not with header and trailer check . generate as a mail with table format of filename and status as 1or 0. If not generated highlight those files using perl

Comment: This question is far too broad as written. You'll have to be more specific on what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Just check file exists or not with header and trailer check . generate as a mail with table format of filename and status as 1or 0. If not generated highlight those files using perl

Comment: @MattJacob  is it okay now?

Comment: You've only slightly restated your original question! Please [tour] [so] and learn [ask] good questions, and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a file exists using

```
if(-e "filename"){
  #file exists
}
else{
  #file does not exist
}
```

> And also it check for file header and trailer.

Not sure what you mean with this, but I guess once you verified that the file exists you can just read its content to check it:

```
open FILE, "filename" or die "Error opening file!\n"
while(my $line=<FILE>){
  #process line
}
```

Comment: What about remote server check if I have password less login using key.. How I can verify?

Comment: And also how to use perl module without installing .. Bcz I can't install in production server .  is there any way I can use.. Placing modules in my own directory and use it from there

Comment: If you don't need to do any operations requiring perl on the remote server I would suggest just executing a command via ssh and processing the output in perl, that way you don't need to install any perl code on the remote machine.  use `$output = \`ssh remote_machine ls filename\`` for example (note the backtick character ( ` ), its not a quote!)